# How do i keep the do while loop from resetting?

Tags: java, exception, input, java.util.scanner, do-while

[Fig.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llBiQ.png)

[Fig.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Om9AX.png)

I suspect my problem is in the do while loop. Please use my code and images for reference.

I managed to make the program take in the only the correct input value even if you enter the incorrect value as you can see from Fig.1.

But it will always reset back to the first input when you are enter the incorrect value in the second or third input. Please see Fig.2 for the output i am looking for.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab4 {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    boolean ok = true;

    do {
    try
    {
        int hours = getHours();
        int minutes = getMinutes();
        int seconds = getSeconds();

        print24HourTime(hours, minutes, seconds);

        ok = true;
    }
    catch (InvalidHrExcep a)
    {
        System.out.println (a.getmessage());
        ok = false;
    } 
    catch (InvalidMinExcep b)
    {
        System.out.println(b.getmessage());
        ok = false;
    }
    catch (InvalidSecExcep c)
    {
        System.out.println (c.getmessage());
        ok = false;
    }
    }while (ok == false);
  }


public static int getHours() throws InvalidHrExcep
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter hours: ");
    int hoursValue = input.nextInt();
    if ((hoursValue < 0 ) || (hoursValue > 12)) {
        throw new InvalidHrExcep("The value of hours must be between 0 and 12");
    }
    return hoursValue;
}

public static int getMinutes() throws InvalidMinExcep
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter minutes: ");
    int minutesValue = input.nextInt();
    if ((minutesValue <0) || (minutesValue > 60))
    {
        throw new InvalidMinExcep("The value of minutes must be between 0 and 60");
    }
    return minutesValue;
}

public static int getSeconds() throws InvalidSecExcep
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter seconds: ");
    int secondsValue = input.nextInt();
    if ((secondsValue <0) || (secondsValue > 60))
    {
        throw new InvalidSecExcep("The value of seconds must be between 0 and 60");
    }
    return secondsValue;
}

public static void print24HourTime(int hr, int min, int sec)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter AM or PM: ");
    String ampm = input.next();
    if ((ampm.equals("am") || (ampm.equals("AM"))))
    {
        System.out.printf("24 hour clock time: %02d:%02d:%02d" , hr, min, sec);         
    }
    if ((ampm.equals("pm") || (ampm.equals("PM"))))
    {
        System.out.printf("24 hour clock time: %02d:%02d:%02d" , hr+12, min, sec);
    }
}
}

class InvalidSecExcep extends Exception{
private String message;

public InvalidSecExcep()
{

}

public InvalidSecExcep(String str)
{
    this.message = str;
}

public String getmessage()  
{
    return this.message;
}

public String tostring()
{
    String c = message;
    return c;
}
}

class InvalidMinExcep extends Exception {
private String message;

public InvalidMinExcep()
{

}

public InvalidMinExcep(String str)
{
    this.message = str;
}

public String getmessage()
{
    return this.message;
}

public String tostring()
{
    String b = message;
    return b;
}
} 

class InvalidHrExcep extends Exception{
private String message;

public InvalidHrExcep()
{

}

public InvalidHrExcep(String str)
{
    this.message = str;
}

public String getmessage()
{
    return this.message;
}

public String tostring()
{
    String a = message; 
    return a;
}
}
```

Comment: I think your error is in your methods, you store the input only when it is  correct. You never store the input when it is incorrect cause of the exception.

Comment: Have a do..while in each method instead of within the main method.  Pass `input` to each method instead of creating new Scanner instances.   The need for the exceptions goes away, and the main method will be smaller/cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple do while loops would work better here.

If you start with a do while on the getting hours, and have a variable check for that when its done, then a seperate one for each other stage.

Would wrap all those ones in one big do while loop. This way, while you are in your big do while loop it will check if each stage is done. Small sudo code example below:

```
bool hours = false
bool min = false
bool seconds = false
Do:

Do(
getHours()
While bool hours = false)


Do(
getmin()
While bool min= false)

Do(
getseconds()
While bool seconds= false)

while ok == false
```

Obviously you have your exceptions tests as well, just to show you the general structure. Can store the values and check to see if they are null as well instead of making bools to check.

Comment: Sorry, i can't make it work. I kept getting syntax error

Comment: Its sudo code, not real code. I am showing you the concept of how it works. If you just tried copying it, you would get syntax errors 100%. Syntax just means you are typing something in wrong, nothing to do with the logic.

Comment: Alright, i managed to make it work thanks to your help. I really appreciate it! Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare Integer hours, Integer minutes ..
2. Store your input when provided with an attribute e.g. `this.hours = getHours();`
3. Test if your attribute is defined e.g. `if(this.hours == null){ this.hours = getHours()}`